# Using two different fonts in font-family

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have my `font-family` defined as

`font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Open Sans', Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;`

My application doesn't have the Helvetica fonts so it should fall back to `Open Sans`(I am downloading Open Sans font on the fly). This fallback is not working and the font `sans-serif` is coming into play instead.

However, when I apply `font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif` to an element, Open Sans does show up as expected.

Please help me figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: A lot of information, to reproduce your problem, is missing from your question. For all I know it could be the quotes or the placement in your code. That's why it is advised to [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or a link, at least.

Comment: On which browser/application does this occur? Tried on IE, can't reproduce.

Comment: I tried it on codepen with a minimal example and I couldn't reproduce, hence, my inability to create an example. Happening only in my project @Spectric

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want to go with the fonts requested in the question, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```css
html
{
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example title</h1>
<p>Example body text here.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that at least Linux hosts have default mapping "Helvetica" => "Arial" which means that if you request plain "Helvetica" *before* "Open Sans", your local host Arial is used instead of webfont nearly always. In general you should assume that "Helvetica", "Times New Roman", "Arial", "Comic Sans" and "Verdana" may refer to any similar styled local font due historical reasons and fallback to any other fonts after those will not happen in practise.

I wouldn't recommend trying to use any local fonts if you want to use downloadable web fonts. Either the system has the *same* font installed locally in which case the font loader CSS emitted by Google fonts will correctly use the locally installed font or the downloaded web font is used always.

As such, I'd recommend using

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
```

instead, if your intent is to render using Open Sans if possible and *fallback* to Helvetica family of fonts before using UA provided `sans-serif` fallback. Also, it's important to understand that `font-family` expect either one of the predefined keywords (e.g. `serif` or `sans-serif`) or a *string*. The original question had `Helvetica` without quotes so it was using keyword syntax and would be ignored by UAs strictly following CSS spec because the keyword is not recognized and as such the rule should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - very informative. I don't want to fall back on Helvetic but fallback on Open Sans - I tried it on codepen and my style query worked! However, in my project, it doesn't. Maybe display=swap is the key. How do I make sure Arial and other font styles you mentioned are not used as fallback before the UA reads Open Sans? To talk about your last point, I haven't really checked it out on Mac yet but on Windows, I don't expect Helvetica. Thanks for the heads up, I will put them as strings.

Comment: The idea is to name the fonts you want to use in strings and then specify one of the 6 fallback *keywords* defined by CSS spec. That way you can ask the system to use whatever is closest to given style in the system and before that you list fonts that you really want to use. However, due historical reasons some font names are treated special by browsers (or even operating systems) but this is not defined in any spec I'm aware of. Basically you want to avoid "Arial", "Helvetica", "Times", "Times New Roman" and "Verdana". And for font names, you have to specify *both* real name and PS name.

Comment: The PS name or Postscript name is needed because Apple wanted to think different and they match on Postscript names instead of font names. Most of the time the Postscript name is the real name followed by space *or* dash followed by style. For example, instead of "Helvetica" you have to write "Helvetica-Bold" or "Helvetica Bold" but it required syntax depends on font manufacturer because this, too, is not defined anywhere and each manufacturer has come up with a different style. If only Apple had done the wise thing and used the proper font name instead...

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with downloading the font on the fly. Your font fallback would certainly work if you included the open sans font into your app from the start.

I don't understand either why you want to download Open Sans on the fly if the user doesn't have Helvetica fonts. Why not just download the Helvetica fonts? Or, why not just include them in your app right away so that you never run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with downloading URL, try with local storage, download font's .woff / .otf file

> store on server / local directory
> use such, hard refresh once, done

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_bold.woff); /* Local file address in parantheses */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```